# Dynamic Zoom on GraphicsPath using GDI+ matrix transforms

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, graphicspath, matrix-transform

I am trying to implement a dynamic zoom on a GraphicsPath where the user draws a rectangle to define a zoom area (see selectRect in the code below). When the user releases the mouse the GraphicsPath is scaled and translated (by a matrix) to the correct position to display the zoomed region in the rectangle defined by 'drawArea'.

The intention is to allow the user to zoom in dynamically a number of times.

The code below for calculating the scale and translation values works perfectly for the first time the user zooms. However any subsequent zoom does not produce the expected result.

```
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            PointF p = ConvertScreenToWorld(new PointF(selectRect.Width, selectRect.Height));
            PointF p2 = ConvertScreenToWorld(new PointF(selectRect.X, selectRect.Y));

            tmpScale = new PointF(drawArea.Width / Math.Max(1, p.X) , drawArea.Height / Math.Max(1, p.Y));
            tmpTranslate = new PointF(-p2.X * tmpScale.X, -p2.Y * tmpScale.Y);

            this.Invalidate();
        }
```

ConvertScreenToWorld()

```
    private PointF ConvertScreenToWorld(PointF PointIn)
    {
        PointF[] p = new PointF[] { PointIn };

        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.Translate(tmpTranslate.X, tmpTranslate.Y);
        m.Scale(tmpScale .X, tmpScale .Y);
        m.Invert();
        m.TransformPoints(p);

        return p[0];
    }
```

Drawing code:
(note the intention is to retain the original path data which is why i am using a clone)

```
        Matrix m2 = new Matrix();
        m2.Translate(tmpTranslate.X, tmpTranslate.Y);
        m2.Scale(tmpScale.X, tmpScale.Y);

        GraphicsPath gpClone2;
        gpClone2 = (GraphicsPath)gp.Clone();
        gpClone2.Transform(m2);
        g.DrawPath(Pens.Blue, gpClone2);
```

Any advice on how to get this to work with cumulative zooms would be much appreciated.

Comment: not an answer, but you would probably be better off setting the transformation on the graphics context instead of setting it on each drawable element.

Comment: not an answer, but your users would probably be a lot happier zooming with the mouse wheel than having to enter some special mode where the application is unusable while requiring them to define a rectangle to zoom into before they can proceed.

Comment: @MikeNakis Thanks for your comments. The GraphicsPath is essentially holding an X/Y graph so i need the user to be able to scale the x and the y  in anyway they want to zoom in on specific areas. If i use the mousewheel then i am fixing the amount i can scale by in each axis.

Comment: _does not produce the expected result_ Is not as helpful as it ought to be.